# Elasticsearch queries not returning all results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to learn Elasticsearch and I have an index with 8 documents. When I run the request (GET):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

The response is:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 8,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "X5jGjXgB0p8Gz5z3KdFE",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "itemId": "01",
          "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
          "disciplineId": "discipline01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "YJjGjXgB0p8Gz5z3eNH4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "02",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
            "disciplineId": "discipline02"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "YZjGjXgB0p8Gz5z3jdHN",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "03",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum02",
            "disciplineId": "discipline01"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "YpjGjXgB0p8Gz5z3tdHl",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "04",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum02",
            "disciplineId": "discipline02"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "Y5jGjXgB0p8Gz5z3w9Gx",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "01",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
            "disciplineId": "discipline01"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "ZJjGjXgB0p8Gz5z30NF5",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "02",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
            "disciplineId": "discipline02"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "ZZjGjXgB0p8Gz5z33NHI",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "03",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum02",
            "disciplineId": "discipline01"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "el1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "ZpjGjXgB0p8Gz5z36dE1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "itemId": "03",
            "curriculumId": "curriculum02",
            "disciplineId": "discipline02"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It has all my documents. But if I run this other request (GET):

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {"disciplineId": "discipline01"}
    }
}
```

It returns just the first document, and if I change it do "discipline02" it returns nothing.
The same happens to the other fields. What I'm doing wrong? I already tried using size:"10" but it doesn't seems to work (I think the default size is already 10).

I'm running this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated) and sending the requests with Insomnia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first document is in this format

```
{
  "itemId": "01",
  "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
  "disciplineId": "discipline01"
}
```

Rest all document are in this format

```
{
  "doc": {
    "itemId": "02",
    "curriculumId": "curriculum01",
    "disciplineId": "discipline02"
  }
}
```

Modify your query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "doc.disciplineId": "discipline02"      // note this
    }
  }
}
```